# Resize of a form and how it effects a dynamicly created listview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that generates a listview dynamically and placed it in a tab control.  When the user resizes the form, I want to capture that event and resize the listview.  I can set the dock property but directly on top of the grid there is a panel with a combo box ( allows user to sort of filter the data).  And when I set the docking the grid docks to the top of the tab and doesn't realize there is a combo there.  Maybe i am doing something wrong.

Here is a sample code:

```
public class KI_Tab_Items_ListviewControl : KI_Tab_Items, IDisposable
{
    private ListView m_Listview = new ListView();
    private ComboBox m_ComboBox = new ComboBox();

    public ListView ListViewControl { get { return m_Listview; } set { m_Listview = value; } }
    public ComboBox ComboBoxControl { get { return m_ComboBox; } set { m_ComboBox = value; } }

    public override void ClearItems()
    {
        ListViewControl.Items.Clear();
    }
    public override void PopulateControls()
    {
        base.PopulateControls();
    }
    public virtual void AddColumnHeaders()
    {
        ListViewControl.Columns.Clear();
    }
    public KI_Tab_Items_ListviewControl(TabControl m_TabControl, int lIndex, bool DisplayComboBox = true)
    {
        if (m_TabControl.TabPages[lIndex].Controls.Count == 0)
        {
            int ListviewTop = 0;
            m_TabControl.TabPages[lIndex].Controls.Clear();
            if (DisplayComboBox)
            {
                m_TabControl.TabPages[lIndex].Controls.Add(ComboBoxControl);
                ComboBoxControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                ComboBoxControl.Visible = true;
                ComboBoxControl.Left = 0;
                ComboBoxControl.Top = 0;
                ListviewTop = ComboBoxControl.Top + ComboBoxControl.Height;
            }

            m_TabControl.TabPages[lIndex].Controls.Add(ListViewControl);

            ListViewControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
            ListViewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            ListViewControl.Visible = true;
            ListViewControl.Top = ListviewTop;
            ListViewControl.Height = m_TabControl.TabPages[lIndex].Height - ListviewTop;
        }
    }
    void System.IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Tab_Control.Controls.Clear();
        m_Listview = null;
        m_ComboBox = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What helps me in situations like this is I like to create a temporary form and use the designer to setup the elements. Then I can look at how the designer codes the controls which directs me to how I can do in manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ListView FIRST. Set **ListViewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill**.
Add ComboBox LAST. Sett **ComboBoxControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top**.

```
public void KI_Tab_Items_ListviewControl( TabControl m_TabControl, int lIndex, bool DisplayComboBox = true )
{
    if ( m_TabControl.TabPages[ lIndex ].Controls.Count == 0 )
    {
        int ListviewTop = 0;

        m_TabControl.TabPages[ lIndex ].Controls.Clear();

        m_TabControl.TabPages[ lIndex ].Controls.Add( ListViewControl );

        // Add ListView FIRST.
        // NOTE: set ListViewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        //

        ListViewControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
        ListViewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ListViewControl.Visible = true;
        ListViewControl.Top = ListviewTop;
        ListViewControl.Height = m_TabControl.TabPages[ lIndex ].Height - ListviewTop;

        // Add ComboBox last.
        // NOTE: set ComboBoxControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        //

        if ( DisplayComboBox )
        {
            m_TabControl.TabPages[ lIndex ].Controls.Add( ComboBoxControl );
            ComboBoxControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            ComboBoxControl.Visible = true;
            ComboBoxControl.Left = 0;
            ComboBoxControl.Top = 0;
            ListviewTop = ComboBoxControl.Top + ComboBoxControl.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It is how the controls are created.  Listview has to be created after the combo box.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `ComboBox` docked to `Top`. If it hides the top of your `Full` docked `ListView` you have to open the Document Outline window and swap `ComboBox` and `ListView` order.
As alternative you can set the `Anchor` property of the `ListView` (for example if you add the `Right` anchor it'll will keep its distance from the right border when resizing the form).

Comment: Hmmm..  It swapped combo and listview as you said.  Setting fill dock for listview just takes over the combo and combo is displayed right on top of the listview.  Any way to say fill dock below a combo?

Comment: Dock= Top for Combo, Dock = Fill for ListView. If overlaps somehow just change their order. Try in a blank form, first put the combo and then the list.

Comment: i tried on a blank form. listview overtakes the combo.  I was hoping Combo on top and then listview on the bottom docked fill.  Thanks for you help BTW

Comment: Invert their order in the Document Outline, they must work in that way! :)

Comment: It's a window you can use as overview of the current document. In you case the form (and you can change controls order by using drag & drop). Open your form, click **View** menu and select **Document Outline** (or press CTRL+ALT+T).